# get list of all nondecreasing sets of list in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

How can I generate all the possible nondecreasing sets of the elements of a list with current length?

```
getSets :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
...

> getSets [0..9] 3
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1]..[3,9,9],[4,4,4]..[8,9,9],[9,9,9]]
```

Comment: `getSets :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start a bit simpler, with a function that produces all sets of the given size from the given list elements:

```
getAllSets :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
getAllSets _  0 = [[]]
getAllSets xs n = [(x:ys) | x <- xs, ys <- getAllSets xs (n-1)]
```

You can think of this function as building the sets one element at a time. It adds `x` onto the front of each shorter set `ys`, and it does this for as many elements as there are in `xs`.

What we can do to get the final answer is decide to not build a longer set for each element in `xs`, but only for those `x` that are less than or equal to every element in `ys`:

```
getSets :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
getSets _  0 = [[]]
getSets xs n = [(x:ys) | x <- xs, ys <- getSets xs (n-1), all (x <=) ys]
```

This is a nice-looking solution, but it does more work than we actually need. After all, why compare `x` against every element in `ys`? We know that `ys` is already in the right order because we've built it that way recursively, so let's just make sure `x` is less than or equal to the first element of `ys`, if there is one:

```
getSets' :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
getSets' _  0 = [[]]
getSets' xs n = [(x:ys) | x <- xs, 
                          ys <- getSets' xs (n-1), 
                          null ys || x <= head ys]
```

**Update**: In addition to incorporating Thomas M. DuBuisson's much cleaner predicate, I also benchmarked his, chrisdb's, and my solutions: http://hpaste.org/50195

**Update x2**: Fixed incorrect Criterion labels; benchmarks were correct but the output was confusing.

Comment: I wonder which of our solutions is faster.... I suspect there's not much between them. You might be doing more comparisons because you don't presort the list, but those should be very cheap for Ints.

Comment: @pelotom: that would be a bit off from the specification of the problem, since even when `xs` is sorted, the first element might be taken from the end, and the second might be taken from the beginning, for example.

Comment: @acfoltzer - oops, I removed my comment a few seconds after posting because I realized it didn't work :)

Comment: One other thing it should do - check that n is positive. Negative n will produce an infinite loop.

Comment: The `ltOrNull` can be more concisely (and readably) written as `null ys || x <= head ys`, thus eliminating the function and just inlining the expression  (notice the `head` there is perfectly safe).

Comment: @TomMD: good call, my aversion to using `head` sometimes goes too far.

Comment: Oh, I did my own timings but for the smaller problem in the initial post. For that problem there are no major differences, but for the bigger problem I can reproduce your findings that your solution is faster. I guess maybe my use of ++ slows things down when the sublists get big.

Answer (score 7):

```
getSets s n = filter nonDec $ replicateM n s
  where nonDec xs = and $ zipWith (>=) (drop 1 xs) xs
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a clean version that should also be rather fast (i.e. it only constructs correct lists and doesn't construct then drop incorrect lists).

```
import Data.List

getSets _ 0 = [[]]
getSets xs n = do
        a <- xs
        rest <- getSets (filter (>= a) xs) (n - 1)
        return (a : rest)
```

EDIT: But it's slower than ACF's - using `filter` is expensive and ACF has intelligently built his lists so a "bad" list will be discovered after adding only one more element for very cheap.  Very nice now that I recognize that.

Comment: @garm0nboz1a How did you determine that?  That was my suspicion when I made it but a Criterion benchmark has made me see otherwise.

Comment: `length $ getSets' [0..9] 8` runs 18secs, and `length $ getSets [0..9] 8` only 0.5 secs

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
import Data.List

getSets :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]

getSets xs n
    | n > 0     = getSets' (sort xs) n
    | otherwise = []

getSets' _ 0          = [[]]
getSets' [] _         = [] 
getSets' xs@(x:xss) n = map (x:) (getSets' xs (n-1)) ++ getSets' xss n
```

Comment: Part of that is because I wanted to check positive n and sort just once before constructing the list. IMO this is better than repeated filtering and the n >= 0 test needs to be done to make the function well behaved. But I agree that the last line is a bit ugly, and something using the List monad on a list comprehension like the others have done might be a bit prettier

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this? For a list x = [a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>], `nondec k x` returns list of all subsequences [a<sub>i<sub>1</sub></sub>, a<sub>i<sub>2</sub></sub>, ..., a<sub>i<sub>k</sub></sub>] of length `k` with i<sub>1</sub> <= i<sub>2</sub> <= ... <= i<sub>k</sub>.

```
import Data.List

nondec 0 _ = return []
nondec n x = do (a,y) <- zip x (tails x)
                map (a:) $ nondec (n-1) y

x = nondec 3 [0..9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done some timings for the [0..9] 3 case, and I get:

```
benchmarking subsets/chrisdb
mean: 193.2204 us, lb 193.0333 us, ub 193.4622 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 1.076765 us, lb 865.2091 ns, ub 1.456463 us, ci 0.950

benchmarking subsets/acfoltzer
mean: 218.5110 us, lb 218.2996 us, ub 218.8322 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 1.309867 us, lb 951.4661 ns, ub 1.793697 us, ci 0.950

benchmarking subsets/TMD
mean: 198.9438 us, lb 194.3482 us, ub 206.6694 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 29.88779 us, lb 20.14344 us, ub 41.98061 us, ci 0.950
```

I excluded the solution of sdcwc because I don't think it solves the problem. In particular, if the initial list is not sorted then it won't produce non-decreasing sub-lists. As you can see, there's not a huge difference but the solutions of Thomas M. DuBuisson and myself are slightly faster on average.

Comment: How do those results scale with larger inputs? I got fairly different results with `[0..20] 5`

Comment: Also, now that I think of it, this should probably be edited into the original answer rather than being separate.

Comment: I reproduce your results for the [0..20] 5 case more or less